# ag-grid Jest testing - this.btFirst.insertAdjacentElement is not a function

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, ag-grid

I try to test ag-grid component using Jest:

```
describe('DataGridInternal Component Tests', () => {
  it('includes class names on DataGrid', () => {
    const component = mount(<DataGridInternal {...SAMPLE_PROPS} />);
    expect(component.find('[data-test="ccfk-datagrid"]')).toHaveClassName('csf-material-grid');

  });
});
```

I get the exception :

`TypeError: this.btFirst.insertAdjacentElement is not a function`

coming from

`node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/lib/rowModels/pagination/paginationComp.js:49`

Once I remark this line the test is passing OK

any idea what is not correct?

I`m using :

```
"ag-grid-community": "21.2.2",       
"ag-grid-react": "21.2.2",
"enzyme": "3.10.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.14.0",
"enzyme-to-json": "3.3.5"
```

Comment: It's reported on the ag-Grid Github issues. This comment fixed it for me: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/3488#issuecomment-571132159

Answer (score 5):

Solution:

> If you're using jest for your test runner, you'll need to upgrade by installing jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen, and adding the following to your jest.config
>
> `testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen'`

and

> If you're using create-react-app,
>
> `npm i -D jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen`
>
> then in your scripts:
>
> `"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom-fourteen",`

Sources: [1](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/3488#issuecomment-567226476) [2](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/3488#issuecomment-571132159)

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same issue as well.

I believe the issue lies in the version of the [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom) package that is being used with `Jest` testing runner.

`insertAdjacentElement` was implemented in version `13.1.0` of `jsdom` as stated in the [changelog](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/c3f0f2756bdbb20e235473728b562e04a67a6555/Changelog.md).

I am running a `create-react-app v2`, which currently does not use this version of `jsdom`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show how you're exactly requiring/importing ag-grid and defining your gridOptions structure? 
I assume you're testing an existing table or a table you defined yourself in HTML?

Comment: it's related to code that was added since version 21.0.0 in ag-grid-community, ```this.btFirst.insertAdjacentElement(....```.  I import the ag-grid import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's wrong, but in my experience such error msg means the class instance is not being instantiated properly (why the method is not being recognized as a function). Get similar errors all the time with JestJS and Puppeteer whenever I slip up in my test object class definitions and try to call their methods in a test.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was neccessary to install "jest-environment-jsdom" along with "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen":

```
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "26.6.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen": "1.0.1",
```

another packages are:

```
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "7.1.2",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
```